# python-requests CSRF verification failed

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a python script to access on a website
But it tells me CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. The python-requests code is as followed:

```
import requests

 payload = {
'inUserName': 'NAN',
'inUserPass': 'NAN'
}

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'From': 'https://pruebita.gob.pe/accounts/login/',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
p = s.post('https://pruebita.gob.pe/accounts/login/', data=payload, headers=headers)

print (p.text)

r = s.get('A protected web page url')
print (r.text)
```

Comment: First you'll need to send get request to your site and obtain csrf token from meta tag in header, then send your post request with header named X-CSRF-TOKEN with your token.

Comment: Its's a public website xd, The CSRF token changes every time I enter the site
The CSRF token changes every time I enter the site, Is there any way to get it during script execution?